# Creating 3 -tier In MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating an Simple Application where A user register his/her name and After Registration he/she Redirect to Login Page ang after login he/she redirect to the Home page.
A Simple Application as i said..
But My concern is that I want to Implement this In MVC3 But using 3-tier Architecture.for this  I created A MVC3 Project named it as Presentation and Created a New Project under Solution and named it as DAL and Shifted the Model Folder in DAL where i have created all the Properties and DbContext and Controller and View in Presentation.So can any one tell me what to keep inside BLL Folder?Please Suggest me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to use MVC as a Presentation layer (as you are doing it right now). Inside of your MVC there will be cases when a model would not be sufficient for you in which case you will need to create ViewModels. You can move the ViewModel to the business layer in which case when BLL retrieves data from DAL, it converts it into some ViewModel with some functionalities and defaults, and send it over to the presentation layer. Once the presentation layer finishes with using the VMs, it passes the data to the BLL which can perform some special validation and some extra business logic. After that it would create model(s) by extracting data from VM and pass it to DAL which can perform transactional update, delete or insert.

Normally my solution at minimum has five projects. I have API project, MVC, Business Layer, Data access layer and Resources.

#### API

This project contains models, interfaces, abstract classes, etc. In essence it contains everything that other layers need to implement. There is usually IRepository for the Repository Pattern implementation, IUnitOfWork for the Unit of Work pattern, models which are either generated by Entity Framework or by hand (but no mappings). ViewModels are also here together with extension methods for converting to and from the models.

#### Business Service Layer

This layer is in charge of fetching the data from the data access layer, converting it to the view model by invoking extension methods, initializing values. Also, if a DAL returns null value, the business service layer will not pass it over to the presentation layer as null, but will return an implementation of the Null Object Pattern. The Null Object Pattern is actually implemented in API and is called by business service layer. This layer references API layer.

#### Data Access Layer

Here you normally implement the repository and unit of work patterns. Instead of directly communicating with EF, you would wrap calls to DbContext into these two implementations. In addition to this, mappings from models to SQL Server tables and columns, as well as foreign keys are done here. This layer references API layer.

#### Resources

All the resources, strings, language translations, etc are located here. This project does not reference API, but Business Service Layer, Data Access Layer and Presentation Layer reference this project to get access to the strings.

#### Presentation layer

This is normally an MVC solution (or if it is Web Forms then there it will be implemented using MVP patter). This solution communicates with Business Service Layer. It receives ViewModels and return values from the business layer. It passes the view models if they are valid to the business layer in order to have them persisted.

#### Linking layers

The layers are connected among themselves using dependency injection. I usually use Unity and configure my application using external configuration settings. This way the Presentation layer, business service layer and data access layer do not have explicit reference. MVC does not hold a direct reference to BLL, BLL does not have a direct reference to DAL. The constructors for controllers and BLL and DAL classes use interfaces and unity passes the appropriate implementation.

Comment: Could you please Elaborate that how i proceed with this?Means Folder by Folder please?I know i am Just about to reach my Destination but not on right path so please Guide me on this!!!Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: I hope this update can help you figure out how to better organize your projects.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably put any Helper methods, Library code or re-usable business logic that the that the controllers use. I often put utility classes and validation logic in here plus any functionality that works with the data obtained from the DBContext Entities.

Comment: Ok..thanks,as i said i have created presentation layer in which i have kept Controller and View but i want that a function to be written in BLL taking one Class and then calling that function in Controller.can it be done?

Comment: It can be done by adding BLL reference to PL but it saying me that it would be Circular Dependency so not permitted...

Comment: Your DLL -> has the reference to DBConext and data CRUD.
     BLL -> (where you write your logic class) References DLL and DB
     MVC -> References both the BLL & DLL
You can then make calls from Controller in MVC to call BLL

Comment: what sholud i do Can you please explain me a bit clearly?In which folder what i should Include and what reference to what?Please!!!

Comment: Under your Solution add a project DLL and put the contents in SolutionFolder\DLL.  Into this folder but all the DbContext and reference System.Entity and so on.  Add another Project to your solution calls BLL and put it in SolutionFolder\BLL.  Reference the DLL project.  FInally in MVC project reference both the DLL and BLL projects